# How do I get the gyroids?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So it was raining and I was exited because I thought I would be able to collect them, so I waited until after it rained and I just couldn’t find them buried anywhere? ( I waited until the rain stopped)  can anyone help? Have I done something wrong...??

Answer (score 2):

Gyroids appear [after rainy or snowy days](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Gyroid_(furniture)) replacing fossils that would spawn. It is not immediately after the rain stops, but the very next day. So you basically need to wait until tomorrow after 6 AM.